# Slow UPDATE appending on array inside JSONB column

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with the following structure (massiveJS default):

```sql
CREATE TABLE "myTable" (
    id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    body jsonb NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamptz NULL DEFAULT now(),
    updated_at timestamptz NULL,
    CONSTRAINT mytable_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

This table has a GIN index on the body column and a btree index on the primary key (default).
The json object stored inside the body column has an array that can grow really large (up to 50k items).
We use this statement to append new items to the array:

```sql
UPDATE "myTable" 
      SET body = jsonb_set(body, '{myArray}', (body->'myArray') 
      || '["item1", "item2", "item3", "itemx""]') 
      WHERE id = 'e6e325da-0e8b-4d2e-9481-bc7e03c195b1'
```

The system updates this array in several records frequently and when the system is under heavy load this UPDATE starts getting really slow, PostgreSQL CPU goes to 100% and the whole application slows down.

Is there any way we could speed up this UPDATE statement in order to append/remove elements from the array without forcing PostgreSQL too much?

Comment: What prevents you from normalising the schema instead of storing arrays in json?

Comment: @Bergi it is an option, but we would have to change some spots in our code and it would take a bit of time. I was just wondering if it`s normal that the update takes that long and uses all the CPU with huge arrays or if we could in some way improve the UPDATE statement until we get the time to normalize the schema

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't do in place updates, so this can't be blazingly fast.  To know if it is just the ordinary slowness or something worse, you would need quantify what "really slow" means.

Comment: @jjanes about 40s when the system is under heavy load

Comment: To update just one row?  That does seem unusually slow.  What if the system is not under heavy load?  I get about 0.5 seconds to add one or a few new entries to a row that already has 50000 entries.  This is with fastupdate off on the GIN index. How many rows does the table have?  Are the entry strings used repeatedly from row to row or are the mostly unique?

Comment: If the system is not under heavy load it takes 1~2 seconds.
This table has 416k rows. Few of them (about 15) are updated with a really high frequency while the others are updated sporadically. Maybe it`s not the UPDATE itself that is taking so long, but the rows that are being updated are locked and PostgreSQL is waiting for the release?